# How to insert data from form to the database while displaying tcpdf

Tags: php, mysql, post, insert, tcpdf

Actually this is a easy task for the php geeks, but im new to the php, my problem describ on the heading as well. when inserting into the database its going to the database with no issue but PDF file wont show like last time. here I attached the coding if some one can help me to get through this appreciated.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","shipping");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())


{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO bldata (blno, Cname, Sadd1, Sadd2, Sadd3, Satel, Coname, Coadd1, Coadd2, Coadd3)
VALUES
('$_POST[blno]','$_POST[Cname]','$_POST[Sadd1]','$_POST[Sadd2]','$_POST[Sadd3]','$_POST[Satel]','$_POST[Coname]','$_POST[Coadd1]','$_POST[Coadd2]','$_POST[Coadd3]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }


mysqli_close($con);


//////////////////////////////
//START OF PDF CREATION
/////////////////////////////
require_once('../config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('../tcpdf.php');




// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('');
$pdf->SetTitle('');
$pdf->SetSubject('');
$pdf->SetKeywords('');

// set default header data
//$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.'', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
```

***it goes so on, and pdf creating also using the $post method .***

Comment: What do you mean "file wont show like last time". Do you want to ignore the new data that has just been saved?

Comment: Hi jeff. Its mean without the database query it will show the pdf file nicely, when I added the mysql query coding on top of the file it insert the data to the database only but not showing pdf file. thnk you

Comment: Are you re-running a query to pick up the values or the $_POST values?

Comment: Yeh I guess. it goes like this $tbl = <<<EOD
<br />



<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">

 <tr>
  <td width="285" height="90">Shipper
  <br />{$_POST['Cname']}
  <br />{$_POST['Sadd1']}
  <br />{$_POST['Sadd2']}
  <br />{$_POST['Sadd3']}
  <br />{$_POST['Satel']}
  <br />
  </td>

Comment: jeff please help me, if you want i can post the full script here. thank you

Comment: Make sure that the table is 100% correct. If there are any errors then tcpdf will not output the data.

Comment: Thank you jeff for ur comments, I think I figure it out using ur clue, i will post the answer.. thnks again

Comment: I Just Remove the "echo" error string from the code -----

    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeh I got it, thanks @jeff for the clue, here is the answer.

remove the "echo" error from the string

```
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

its look like this;;

```
  {
 . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```